# Solving system of linear equations involving 3x3 matrix using adjoint matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> Solve the following system using the adjoint matrix.
>                                     $$2x+4y-10z=-2$$
>                                     $$3x+9y-21z=0$$
>                                      $$x+5y-12z=1$$

Now, I have tried to solve it, and I got the determinant of matrix $A$ is equal to zero. What is the solution of the above system? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant of the matrix is $-6$:
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4 & -10 \\
3 & 9 & -21 \\
1 & 5 & -12
\end{bmatrix}
=
-216-84-150+90+210+144=-6
$$
Thus the system has a single solution. Write it as $AX=B$, where
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4 & -10 \\
3 & 9 & -21 \\
1 & 5 & -12
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
X=\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}
\quad
B=\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and use that
$$
\operatorname{adj}A\cdot A=(\det A)I_3
$$
so you get
$$
(\det A)X=\operatorname{adj}A\cdot B
$$

Answer (score 1):

The system of equation can be expressed in the matrix form as:
$$\begin{pmatrix}2&4&-10\\ 3&9&-21\\1&5&-12\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} \iff AX=B.$$
The formula to find $X$:
$$AX=B \iff A^{-1}AX=A^{-1}B \iff X=A^{-1}B=\frac{\text{adj}A}{|A|}B.$$
The [determinant of $A$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=deteminant%20%7B%7B2,4,-10%7D,%7B3,9,-21%7D,%7B1,5,-12%7D%7D) (performing row operations):
$$|A|=\begin{vmatrix}2&4&-10\\ 3&9&-21\\1&5&-12\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}0&-6&14\\ 0&-6&15\\1&5&-12\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}0&0&-1\\ 0&-6&15\\1&5&-12\end{vmatrix}=-6.$$
The [adjoint of $A$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=adjugate%20%7B%7B2,4,-10%7D,%7B3,9,-21%7D,%7B1,5,-12%7D%7D):
$$\text{adj}A=(C_{ij})^{\text{T}}=\begin{pmatrix}9(-12)-(-21)5&-(4(-12)-(-10)5)&4(-21)-(-10)9\\ -(3(-12)-(-21)1)&2(-12)-(-10)1&-(2(-21)-(-10)3)\\3\cdot 5-9\cdot 1&-(2\cdot 5-4\cdot 1)&2\cdot 9-4\cdot 3\end{pmatrix}=\\
=\begin{pmatrix}-3&-2&6\\ 15&-14&12\\6&-6&6\end{pmatrix}$$
Can you calculate $X$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Since the determinant of the coefficient matrix is zero, the system of linear equations has no unique solution. Try to find the row echelon form of the augmented matrix $(A|B)$ , where $A$ is the coefficient matrix, and $B$ is the matrix of the right side. This will help.

Comment: P.S. if you find it difficult to solve, tell me, I'll solve it explicitly.